# optimal maximum size for nodequeue in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, nodequeue

I have set the queue size as '0' which means an infinite as we know well. I have added 777 nodes in that queue so far. But the problem is, now I cannot view the nodequeue.

I got the following message when I view that particular nodequeue.

"You are here

Home » Homepage Mosaic

Subqueue 'Homepage Mosaic'

Add to Default  shortcuts"

I have another nodequeue which has 129 nodes as of now, I can view that page. How can I solve the problem? Is there any optimal size for queue??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see the dblog? Maybe you have memory problems and the 777 nodes can't showed.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is mainly going to be dictated by how much memory is available to Drupal and how much of it PHP is allowed to use via `memory_limit` (and to a lesser extent how much traffic your site gets which competes for memory). Paginating your results so that only 10/20/X nodes show per page can keep you from running out of memory.